# Team Foundation Server let users with web access see other bugs also

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have a group of users in Team Foundation Server. These users can only access TFS via the web to report bugs and issues.

The problem is that they only see their own reported bugs. Is it possible to let this group also see bugs and issues from the overall project instead of just their own, but without giving them too many permissions? They should be able to see the other bugs/issues but not be able to edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the users mentioned have been added to a group named **Work Item Only View Users** found at the server level on TFS (in TFS 2010).  [Here is a blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/serkani/how-to-enable-work-item-only-view-in-team-web-access-2010) that covers this well.

Adding users to this group sets it up so that they can only see the ones they create. It also means that they do not require a Client Access License (CAL) for TFS;  You can remove them from this group, which will imply that your company already has the CALs that cover these users.  For information about the licensing, please see the latest version of the [Visual Studio 2010 Licensing Whitepaper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350), last updated April 2012. See the section titled *When A Client License is not Required*.

If you are not worried about the CALs so much because your users are covered, etc... then you can take them out of that group and limit their permissions with a fair level of granularity. I can't post more links on this site yet because this is my first post on superuser, but you can check out the topic *Team Foundation Server Permissions* on Microsoft's MSDN site for details about what is possible.